# Insert to datagridview when SELECT query has WHERE condition

Tags: c#, .net, sql, winforms

I use this code to Load and Insert data to a table using a `DataGridView` in a C# windows application.

```
        SqlCommand sCommand;
        SqlDataAdapter sAdapter;
        SqlCommandBuilder sBuilder;
        DataSet sDs;
        DataTable sTable;          
private void form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {    
                string connectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
                string sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                connection.Open();
                sCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                sAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sCommand);
                sBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sAdapter);
                sDs = new DataSet();
                sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "mytable");
                sTable = sDs.Tables["mytable"];
                connection.Close();
                dataGridView1.DataSource = sDs.Tables["mytable"];
                dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
                save_btn.Enabled = false;
                dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
            }

            private void new_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                dataGridView1.ReadOnly = false;
                save_btn.Enabled = true;
                new_btn.Enabled = false;
                delete_btn.Enabled = false;
            }

            private void delete_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index);
                    sAdapter.Update(sTable);
                }
            }

            private void save_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                sAdapter.Update(sTable);
                dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
                save_btn.Enabled = false;
                new_btn.Enabled = true;
                delete_btn.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
```

It's ok and works, but when I try to work with a query that has a condition then no rows are added to the `DataGrid` and `MyTable` anymore

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable where col2 = 1";
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your code should work and output rows if your database contains records corresponding to your condition.

Since we are on a code review site I would like to highlight several code issues not related to your question:

- You should dispose all objects implementing `IDisposable` interface.  In your code these objects are `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataAdapter`. Easiest way to dispose objects properly is via `using` statement (note that you [don't need to close connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195829/do-i-have-to-close-a-sqlconnection-before-it-gets-disposed) if you dispose it).
- You don't need to use `DataSet` to populate a `DataTable`, you can populate `DataTable` directly from `DataAdapter`.
- Initialization of controls (`dataGridView1.ReadOnly`, `dataGridView1.SelectionMode` and `save_btn.Enabled` in `form1_Load`) can be done at design time, so that your code is not cluttered with it.

As a result of described transformations your code may look like this:

```
private void form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable";

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
    {
        connection.Open();
        var myTable = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(myTable);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = myTable;
    }
}
```

This code is good enough for simple project, but it won't allow you to unit-test your project. If you start looking in this direction prepare to spend quite some time learning [ORM frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) and [Inversion of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control).

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems in your code, to name a few:

- you don't close the connection nor dispose any of the `problematic` objects (SqlConnection, SqlCommand and SqlDataAdapter). Yes, I see you're using them later in the code, but trust me, it's a BAD idea
- as almaz already pointed out, you don't need `DataSet` in this situation at all

What I'm troubled with the most is of a different matter:
You don't separate layers at all! You mix and match UI logic, business logic and data access into one big ugly mess. This looks like a procedural code, completely ignoring every OOP rule. How did you come to the conclusion that your `Form` should be aware (and responsible!!!) for objects like `SqlConnection`?

What you should do in the first place is to separate your logic into layers. For instance [**this**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture) is a good place to start reading and learning the theory.

If you fix this, I believe you won't have problems like this anymore, because you would be able to find the problem more easily without any external help.